# PHP foreach and after that while loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I currently have a query which fetches data and then runs another query. I then echo out the results of the second query. What I would like to do is to move the echo outside of the foreach loop please but I don't know how to do that.

```
$ids = 2,3;
$id = explode(",",$ids);

$barcode = array();

foreach($id as $value) {
    $sql_query = $db->prepare("SELECT barcode FROM product WHERE id=:value");
    $sql_query->bindParam(":value", $value);
    $sql_query->execute();
    $row = $sql_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $barcode = $row['barcode'];


    /* I want to move this part starting from here outside the foreach */ 

    $sql_select_all = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE barcode=:barcode");
    $sql_select_all->bindParam(":barcode", $barcode);
    $sql_select_all->execute();
    while($row = $sql_select_all->(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $name = $row['name'];
        $img = $row['image'];
        $desc = $row['desc'];

        echo $name.$img.$desc;
    }
    /* ending here */

}
```

How can I move the echo line out of the foreach loop?

Comment: cut and paste? What's stopping you?

Comment: that's really nice.. funny..

Comment: It's meant to point out that you haven't actually described what your issue is. No one can help you if you haven't told us what is stopping you from moving it out. Why can't you simply move it below the foreach loop? Have you tried? What happens if you do?

Comment: ok.. i need the barcode from my 1st query to run the second query which is within the foreach loop.. so moving that outside i will get only the last barcode and not the both..

Comment: Right, so you want to run the echo outside of your loop?

Comment: yes... exactly.. not so good at english.. that's why i got 2 downvotes.. it's my fault..

Comment: I can help, I will post an answer in a second.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
foreach($id as $value){
$sql_query = $db->prepare("SELECT barcode FROM product WHERE id=:value");
$sql_query->bindParam(":value", $value);
$sql_query->execute();
$row = $sql_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// make array with the entry
$barcode[] = '"'.$row['barcode'].'"';    
}
// after foreach we explode the array and add comma , 
$barcode = explode(',',$barcode)

// using mysql ( [IN][1] ) query instead of ( = )
$sql_select_all = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE barcode in ($barcode)'");
$sql_select_all->bindParam(":barcode", $barcode);
$sql_select_all->execute();
while($row = $sql_select_all->(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

$name = $row['name'];
$img = $row['image'];
$desc = $row['desc'];

echo $name.$img.$desc;
```

[using IN() Function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php)

Comment: ok that's nice..  but if i have an `echo` like this : `echo <div id="i want to use the productid here.">$name.$img.$desc</div>;` then what will i do?

Comment: i added the reference of IN ()

Comment: u may use join table or alter table with product id in invetory table

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is store the results of your second query into an array. Then you can move the echo out of the for loop and run a loop on your new array like this:

```
$ids = 2,3;
$id = explode(",",$ids);

$barcode = $results = array();

foreach($id as $value){
    $sql_query = $db->prepare("SELECT barcode FROM product WHERE id=:value");
    $sql_query->bindParam(":value", $value);
    $sql_query->execute();
    $row = $sql_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $barcode = $row['barcode'];


    /*i want to move this part starting from here outside the foreach*/ 

    $sql_select_all = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE barcode=:barcode");
    $sql_select_all->bindParam(":barcode", $barcode);
    $sql_select_all->execute();
    while($row = $sql_select_all->(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $results[] = $row;
        //$name = $row['name'];
        //$img = $row['image'];
        //$desc = $row['desc'];

        //echo $name.$img.$desc;
    }
    /*ending here*/
    foreach($results as $row) {
        echo $row['name'] . $row['image'] . $row['desc'];
    }

}
```